# Vue.js (Nuxt) Return JSON Data

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, vue.js

I tried making a `JSON` API using `Nuxt.js`. But I requested a URL and html code was returned (source code of website. Like: `view-source:https://website.com`).

**How can I get `JSON` returned instead?**

Here is the API code:

```js
<template>
    <div>
        {{user}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import data from "../assets/data.json";

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            user: data
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And here is returned data, the `html` source of the website (I tried work on localhost):

```html
<!doctype html> <html data-n-head-ssr lang="en" data-n-head="%7B%22lang%22:%7B%22ssr%22:%22en%22%7D%7D"> <head > <title>drackin-api</title> <meta data-n-head="ssr" charset="utf-8"> <meta data-n-head="ssr" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <meta data-n-head="ssr" data-hid="description" name="description" content=""> <meta data-n-head="ssr" name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"> <link data-n-head="ssr" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico"> <link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/runtime.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/commons/app.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/vendors/app.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/pages/bot.js" as="script"><style data-vue-ssr-id="3191d5ad:0"> .nuxt-progress { position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; height: 2px; width: 0%; opacity: 1; transition: width 0.1s, opacity 0.4s; background-color: black; z-index: 999999; } .nuxt-progress.nuxt-progress-notransition { transition: none; } .nuxt-progress-failed { background-color: red; } </style><style data-vue-ssr-id="0e36c2db:0"> .nuxt__build_indicator[data-v-71e9e103] { box-sizing: border-box; position: fixed; font-family: monospace; padding: 5px 10px; border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); width: 88px; z-index: 2147483647; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.2rem; } .v-enter-active[data-v-71e9e103], .v-leave-active[data-v-71e9e103] { transition-delay: 0.2s; transition-property: all; transition-duration: 0.3s; } .v-leave-to[data-v-71e9e103] { opacity: 0; transform: translateY(20px); } svg[data-v-71e9e103] { display: inline-block; vertical-align: baseline; width: 1.1em; height: 0.825em; position: relative; top: 1px; } </style> </head> <body > <div data-server-rendered="true" id="__nuxt"><!----><!----><div id="__layout"><pre> [object Object] </pre></div></div><script>window.__NUXT__=(function(a){return {layout:"default",data:[{}],fetch:{},error:a,serverRendered:true,routePath:"\u002Fbot",config:{_app:{basePath:"\u002F",assetsPath:"\u002F_nuxt\u002F",cdnURL:a}},logs:[]}}(null));</script><script src="/_nuxt/runtime.js" defer></script><script src="/_nuxt/pages/bot.js" defer></script><script src="/_nuxt/commons/app.js" defer></script><script src="/_nuxt/vendors/app.js" defer></script><script src="/_nuxt/app.js" defer></script> </body> </html>
```

But this is what I want returned:

```json
{
  "username": "drackin",
  "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
  "location": "Turkey"
}
```

How can I do this? Any help is appreciated .